# Map 2d rectangular image to 4 coordinate points in Java

Tags: java, image, coordinates

I have a rectangular image of some bricks and I would like to map it to a Java canvas screen where each corner point of the rectangle is defined. For example, I want the top left corner of the image to be at point x, y (0,2), the bottom left corner defined at (0,0), top right corner defined at (2,3), and bottom right corner defined at (2,0). As you can see, the top right corner of the image is slightly higher/stretched up in comparison to the other corners of the image. Is there a Java library that can do this sort of thing?

In short: I want to define each corner coordinate of a rectangular image, but don't know how.

Comment: Do you want the image to be stretched?  You may need to define your own transformation matrix (hope you maths is good ;)).  Something like `AffineTransform` might help

Comment: Yes, stretched at that top right corner